# Page redirect not loading

Tags: javascript, redirect

For some reason, this page won't go to the mobile or desktop page when I use it! Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Loading...</title>
    </head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
        var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/g) ? true : false );
        if (iOS == true) {
        window.location.href="http://m.lifewithzooza.x10host.com/";
        } else {
        window.location.href="http://lifewithzooza.x10host.com/wordpress/";
        }
    </script>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        Loading...
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry, this is my first time on Stack Overflow, so I'm not familiar with some stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing `}` for `onload` function. Update code to following.

```
window.onload = function() {
        var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/g) ? true : false );
        if (iOS == true) {
        window.location.href="http://m.lifewithzooza.x10host.com/";
        } else {
        window.location.href="http://lifewithzooza.x10host.com/wordpress/";
        }
}
```

Comment: @ZoozaS - Not a problem :)

Comment: @ZoozaS note you also have to [move the script element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31493455/3541881).

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - I totally agree. You need to more your script element either in head or body element

Answer (score 0):

You have missing **}** . so its not working. You have missed **}** for the `window.onload = function() { //your code goes here }`

Please check running code here

```js
 window.onload = function() {
        var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/g) ? true : false );
        if (iOS == true) {
        window.location.href="http://m.lifewithzooza.x10host.com/";
        } else {
        window.location.href="http://lifewithzooza.x10host.com/wordpress/";
        }
   }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Loading...</title>
    </head>
   
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        Loading...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

- You've put your `script` element in the wrong place, in the middle of nowhere. The script tag must be under `body` or `head` and nothing else. As said at [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1): `The SCRIPT element places a script within a document. This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document.`
- You also missed a `}` on your `onload` function:

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Loading...</title>
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/g) ? true : false );
            if (iOS) {
                window.location.href="http://m.lifewithzooza.x10host.com/";
            } else {
                window.location.href="http://lifewithzooza.x10host.com/wordpress/";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        Loading...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Meh. I don't really use standard DOM methods. :)